# arguments for hasPermission in a generic controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-el

I am trying implement a generic controller class where each method has a structure similar to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_#this.class.name')")
public ModelAndView cadastra() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return new ModelAndView("privado/"+this.entity.getClass().getName()+"/cadastra", "command", this.entity.getClass().newInstance());
}
```

I am having trouble with the annotation `PreAuthorize`. the name for the permissionhave this structure: _. right now, I am getting a 403 Error when I try access the view mapped by the method. I also tried other variations like:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.class.name)")
```

or

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_#this.getClass().getName()')")
```

but with the same result. Anyone knows the right way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

I try call this function inside the methods from controller secured by this tag PreAuthorize:

```
private void expressionParser() {
    System.out.println("expressionHandler()");
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("'cadastra_'+#this.class.name");
    String message = (String) expression.getValue();
    System.out.println("Message is " + message);
}
```

and when I run the application and open the view should be mapped by a method from controller, like this one:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.class.name)")
public ModelAndView cadastra() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    this.expressionParser();
    return new ModelAndView("privado/"+this.entityClass.getName()+"/cadastra", "command", this.entityClass.newInstance());
}
```

No message is displayed on the console. So, I am thinking my application somehow aren't calling the methods from my generic controller. Am I right? If so, how I fix this?

My derived controllers follow this structure:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="usuario")
public class UsuarioController extends controller<Usuario> {

    public UsuarioController() {
        super(Usuario.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do I get it right that the permission should have the form of [methodName]_[classFullName]? Could you add your Spring Security configuration related to access control?

Comment: Yes, that's the format for the permission. The spring security configuration is this: https://github.com/klebermo/blog.cms/tree/master/src/main/java/com/config/security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I solved this issue with this approach:

1) Adding a new method to my generic controller, where I return the name of the class:

```
public String getName() {
    String expressao = entityClass.getName();
    String nome_classe = new String();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expressao, ".");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        nome_classe = st.nextToken();
    }
    return nome_classe;
}
```

2) Inside the annotation, I use the returned value by this method and concatenate the result with the constant string (using the notation described by the user @pgjecek in this topic):

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
```

and now it1s working perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

So you have difficulties with dynamic construction of permission name in the form of [methodName]_[classFullName] in SpEL expression.

See what SpEL documentation says about #this variable below

> The variable #this is always defined and refers to the current evaluation object 
>   (against which unqualified references are resolved).

Based on the documentation and a bit digging in the code the actual object the #this represents should be in your case an instance of  `org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot` class. The class contains several helpful methods among others also `getThis()` method that returns the target object on which the secured method (a method annotated with `@PreAuthorize`) is being invoked.

Armed with this knowledge it should not be a big deal to construct the expression you require. In case of method named "cadastra", it should be as follows.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.class.name)")
```

Hopefully it will also work correctly for secured methods inherited from a base class.